# Combine Pandas dataFrames into a labelled JSON file

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have two separate train and validation dataFrames, train_df and val_df, that both look like below (with varying values in the lists, ints and strings):

```
F1      F2 F3
[0,0,0] 1  'string1'
[1,2,1] 2  'string2'
...     ... ...
```

And I'd like to save them into a single JSON file with the following format:

```
{
    "training":[
        {
            "F1": [0,0,0]
            "F2": 1
            "F3": 'string1'
        },
        {
            "F1": [1,2,1]
            "F2": 2
            "F3": 'string2'
        }
    ],
    "validation":[
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

where the validation section is structured as the training section (F1,F2,F3) but with different values.

The closest I've gotten is using `train_df.to_json(orient="records")` which results in the right substructure, but I'm struggling to figure out how to insert the top level training or validation identifier. One option I've thought of is to save both dataframes separately, then read them in and store as strings using `.dumps` and then insert the text in the required location, but that seems overly convoluted and I'm sure there must be a more pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it.

```
final_json={'training':df1.to_dict('records'),'validation':df2.to_dict('records')}
'''
{
    "training": [
        {
            "F1": "[0,0,0]",
            "F2": 1,
            "F3": "'string1'"
        },
        {
            "F1": "[1,2,1]",
            "F2": 2,
            "F3": "'string2'"
        }
    ],
    "validation": [
        {
            "F1": "[0,0,0]",
            "F2": 1,
            "F3": "'string1'"
        },
        {
            "F1": "[1,2,1]",
            "F2": 2,
            "F3": "'string2'"
        }
    ]
}
'''
```

Comment: Thank you. This did the work far more neatly than my code, and I could simply save the new dictionary using the usual `json.dumps` and `json.dump`.

Comment: Sorry I missed the save part. So do you have a problem now?

Comment: No, the saving was easy enough following the standard save logic, it was getting the data into the right format that I was struggling with. Thank you for your help, it was much appreciated.